# Maven : mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies not working with dependencies in parent pom

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I had all my dependencies in a module1/pom.xml. 
Now I have introduced module2/pom.xml and the common dependencies are moved to parent/pom.xml

Earlier I used to run "mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies" on module1/pom.xml and it was working fine. But after introducing parent pom.xml it is not working.

I think, it is due to the fact, there is no dependencies tag in module1/pom.xml

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you have parent pom.xml where all common dependency mentioned for Module A and Module B. Then you need to run maven command from parent folder to build all modules.

You can refer this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for more details.